# How to sort one array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to print out an unsorted version of an array and a sorted version of array using this code:

```js
var sortArrayNumber = function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
};

var array = [5, 2, 1044, 3, 126];
var sortedArray = [];

sortedArray = array;

sortedArray.sort(sortArrayNumber);

document.write(array + " and " + sortedArray);
```

This is not the actual code that I'm going to use, I'm just testing it.
And when I test it using jsfiddle, it outputs

```
2,3,5,126,1044 and 2,3,5,126,1044
```

But I want it to output

```
5,2,1044,3,126 and 2,3,5,126,1044
```

So, how do I stop it from doing that?

*BTW, I'm self teaching myself JavaScript so my knowledge of it isn't great*

Comment: `sort` sorts the array in place. You need to clone the array before you sort it. See [Copying array by value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7486085/218196)

Comment: @FelixKling make it an answer :)

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7486085/1715004

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply the sort on a copy of the original array with [Array#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice),

> The `slice()` method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object.

because sort works in place.

```
sortedArray = array.slice();
```